# Avconv unrecognized option sseof

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I try to extract the last frames of some videos with Avconv(FFmpeg):

```
avconv -sseof -10 -i "inputfile.mp4" -vf "select='eq(n,0)'" -vframes 1 output.PNG
```

But I get this error:

> unrecognized option sseof

I looked at help and didn't found any sseof option there. Searched the Internet and couldn't find anything about this problem!

~> OS = Raspbian.

Comment: ffmpeg has this option. avconv is [not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9477115/5726027) as ffmpeg.

Comment: @Smock Yes, the problem is that there is no "sseof" option!

Comment: Then I'd recommend to use ffmpeg.

Comment: @Gyan Yeah, that was the problem... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`avconv` does not have this option, and it is [different from `ffmpeg`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9477115/5726027).

Use a real ffmpeg (e.g. via http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) instead, and you will have support for this option. Static builds work fine on most systems.

Comment: Thanks and sorry that I can't upvote. I dont have enough reputation!
And yeah... I used this page to install ffmpeg on Raspbian:
http://jollejolles.com/installing-ffmpeg-with-h264-support-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: No problem, I just posted the answer to get this question answered. You can tick the green checkmark next to it to mark it as solved.